# Почему в команде msqldump вместо username работает имя от БД?

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh

Всем доброго времени суток, господа. Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой создания дампа, зайдя под своим рутом через ssh сделал команду вида

```
mysqldump -u USER -p DATABASE > /var/dump.sql
```

Введя вместо user моего созданного пользователя на сервере centos 6 выдается ошибка:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1044: "Access denied for user 'USERsNAME'@'localhost' to database 'nameDATABASE '" when selecting the database

В итоге вместо user подставил имя бд и все заработало. Думаю это и есть данные для входа, которые нужны. Исходя из этого опыта при попытке создать подключение на c# использовал имя БД, но получаю тоже самое сообщение:

> Authentication to host 'myhost' for user 'DATABASEsNAME' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'DATABASEsNAME'@'176.59.212.182' (using password: YES)

Код c#:

```
string serverName = "myHost";
string userName = "DATABASEsNAME";
string dbName = "DATABASEsNAME";
string port = "3306";
string password = "myPassWord";
string connection = "server=" + serverName +
            ";user=" + userName +
            ";database=" + dbName +
            ";port=" + port +
            ";password=" + password + ";";
 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
 conn.Open();
```

На севере в конфиге закомментировал строку skip-networking для удаленного подключения. До этого стояла панель ispManager. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем загвоздка.

Comment: Ну так вы используете не имя БД или юзера, а строку "DATABASEsNAME", о чём вам в ошибке и пишут

Comment: вместо этих данных я свои подставляю

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему в одном вопросе описываются две в принципе не связанные вещи. `вместо user подставил имя бд и все заработало` - проверяйте созданных пользователей, косяк там, ибо чудес не бывает.

Comment: А еще вы должны явно создать пользователя username@176.59.212.182 и дать ему доступ к базе, если хотите подключаться удаленно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, да, нужно было дать права пользователю. До этого я пробовал это сделать, но не получалось, потому что не под рутом заходил, но и под рутом не с первого раза зашел, оказалось пароля на mysql -u root -p не было, поэтому зашел только после команды mysql -u root, затем дал все привилегии для username@176.59.212.182 командами:

```
CREATE USER username@176.59.212.182 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'176.59.212.182' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

После этого в c# ввёл все, как и положено.

```
string serverName = "myHost";
string userName = "username";
string dbName = "DATABASEsNAME";
string port = "3306";
string password = "Database's PassWord";
string connection = "server=" + serverName +
            ";user=" + userName +
            ";database=" + dbName +
            ";port=" + port +
            ";password=" + password + ";";
 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
 conn.Open();
```

Чтобы разрешить удаленное подключение любым ip адресам прописать:

```
'username'@'%'
```